# How would telekinesis change warfare?

Tags: magic, warfare, medieval

Another book idea. I'm shooting these things out to cull the unreasonable ones.

In my world, which is set in a medieval setting on Earth, 1/1000 people have a magical telekinesis power. Let's call them wizards. They can move objects with their mind, applying a moderate force. The force is on the order of 50 N applied per second for the average wizard, and this force can't be applied over an area less than 25in^2, or for more than 10 seconds. For example, they can lift an arrow and send it flying, but they can't lift a whole person. This telekinesis manifests at the age of 12. This telekinesis power has a range of 1 km for the average wizard and needs line of sight, but has moderate control at best, eg. they can lift a sword, but they can't direct it into someone's hand. Wizards can only control one object at a time.

How would battle tactics in combat between equally-sized and equally equipped armies change in the presence of these wizards (specifically, the tactics of the non-wizards)? Assume that that the cost to hire these wizards is negligible, since that's a waste of time to think about.

Edit: Wizards can't use their telekinesis on themselves to jump higher, but they can affect their own clothes, weapons, etc. to attack harder, etc.

Comment: This is too broad and subject to too much opinion. Please remember SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. You're basically asking us to rewrite medieval battle tactics and you can't objectively choose between "it wouldn't change a thing" and "it would change everything." This Q might be askable if you choose a single medieval battle such that we know *exactly* what all other circumstances are.

Comment: Can you explain their powers in a context similar to what they would understand in that time?
I mean they can left a cart full of sword an move it 500 before getting tired.
This physics talk seems to out of characters for such a world.

Comment: @JBH there are many other questions that do the same thing. I remember a question similar to this, that involved falling bricks. It was actually more open-ended than my question. 'Twas How could flying soldiers influence medieval battle tactics?

Comment: "*they can lift an arrow and send it flying*" how does that compare to an archer? "*Wizards can't use their telekinesis on themselves to jump higher, but they can affect their own clothes, weapons, etc. to attack harder, etc*" Does not follow. If they cannot affect themselves to jump higher but can affect their clothes, can't they just lift their shoes while they are in air? Doesn't seem much different to doing whatever it is they would do in order to attack harder. You need to put more force behind a punch so it's some variation of magically pushing their fist as they swing.

Comment: can they do fencing/moving around while using their telekinesis to lift another sword or they need to stand still and concentrate to do so? i am not good with math, but from what i get, they can only lift it for 10 second? and only lift light weight?(doesnt seem good for provision if its true), if it the latter seems pretty sucky, they are at best can direct enemy arrow away or enemy melee weapon away for a bit to open a gap during combat.

Comment: also enemy probably wont wear long cape or long loose clothes like robe/dress (including loose chainmail, depend on the math) in order to not get tangled or lifted by the wizard to disturb your limbs and vision (outside of your dignity), so your wizard probably wont wear the typical wizard clothing like loose robe (unless they can counter each other from doing so). while the scabbard will be slipped in tight belt within your body like japanese samurai do rather than loose belt that hanging around the sword scabbard to make sure it secured well from getting manipulated by the wizard.

Comment: @The_CIA, That the rules are applied inconsistently is a problem on all Stacks. If you believe I treated you improperly, post a question in Meta to have it reviewed. Thanks.

Comment: @The_CIA one more thing. Rules change over time. HDE's post in 2015 was accommodated by rules that don't exist anymore. Indeed, the reasons to close have changed considerably since those days. Therefore, and not surprisingly, old questions don't set a precedent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizards aren't doing any actual fighting. Instead, what they do is move provisions quickly to troops in need, such as potions, weapons, shields, etc. They can also use their telekinetic powers to halt advancing troops, allowing the soldiers they're supporting to safely retreat or take advantage of the vulnerable enemies.

If multiple telekinetic wizards use their power in tandem, they could also defend against opposing weaponry, such as catapults or even fireballs from more conventional wizards. A group of wizards might also be useful in taking down an airborne enemy by limiting their flight.